# working with javascript jsonp callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We are using JSONP method while working javascript to avoid Cross-Domain problem.

But I could not understand the logic. I am using a service that returns a result like this:

```
parseResponse({"type":"FeatureCollection",......})
```

Servcice link is here: http://giswebservices.massgis.state.ma.us/geoserver/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&SRS=EPSG:26986&BBOX=11830.0,776202.9449152543,348201.0,961492.0550847457&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=390&INFO_FORMAT=text/javascript&FEATURE_COUNT=100&QUERY_LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&X=120&Y=109&FORMAT&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS

I am using it in a JQuery ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $(".test").html(json.type);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e);
    }
});
```

This ajax always works error function. But request result is coming true. How can I catch parseResponse callback function?

Here is my working code http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/E9j7c/

Comment: Since that's JSONP you have to set `dataType` to `'jsonp'`, not `'json'`. See [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score -1):

As the service returns a jsonp response by default, even without your custom callback parameter, the fastest solution I found is to get the response text from the error and evaluate it:

```
var url = "http://giswebservices.massgis.state.ma.us/geoserver/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&SRS=EPSG:26986&BBOX=11830.0,776202.9449152543,348201.0,961492.0550847457&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=390&INFO_FORMAT=text/javascript&FEATURE_COUNT=100&QUERY_LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&X=120&Y=109&FORMAT&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS";

function parseResponse( data ) {
    console.log( 'parse', data );
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {

    },
    error: function(e) {
        eval(e.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: my service link dierctly returns my_callback({...}) result, it does not need callback parameter. So can I use it as if JSONP